# Easiest/best way to UV unwrap several adjanced rooms?

Tags: texturing, uv

First of all, I don't get the UV unwrapping in general, like at all... Literally all I understand it is what I need to have textures on the model (I want to export it into Unity).

Anyway, I have [this model](https://imgur.com/a/J9YH7), what would be the best way to unwrap it, or better, how to unwrap it at all?

Comment: Probably the option called "smart UV project" in your case (it keeps all the surfaces uniform and optimize the needed space of the texture). But things may depend on how many textures/materials will be needed for your project.

Comment: I am limited to help you further as I don't know what is possible in Unity (many materials per model, how UV maps are organized... ?)... so I hope someone else with better skills can help you. But out of that, it seems logical to unwrap per material (example : floors, wall of room1, wall of room2, ...)

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, I need to apply different materials to different walls floors and etc... Thanks.